# I want to make a call from my adapter class in recyclerview

Tags: java, android

normal intent isn't working in adapter class for action call. how can I make a call from my adapter class for recyclerview?

```
  callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String phoneNo2 = itemNumber.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
                                   Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo2));
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I had to add this context to write startactivity..Otherwise startactivity isn't coming.

Answer (score 1):

`View` has a reference to `Context` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getContext())):

```
v.context.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add recyclerview to design
2. define recyclerview and onclick call button like below,

   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>

   {

   ```
    // RecyclerView recyclerView;  
    public MyAdapter(MyListData[] listdata) {  

    }  
    @Override  
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {  
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());  
        View Itemis= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file, parent, false);  
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(Itemis);  
        return viewHolder;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {  

    }  

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
        public Button callbutton;  

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {  
            super(itemView);  
            this.callbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);  
            ///here is button clikc

            callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phoneNo2 = itemNumber.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
                    Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo2));
                    v.context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }); 
        }  
    }
   ```

   }

if any query comment it.

Answer (score 0):

- add permission in manifest...

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

- add this code on click..

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```